# Making phone calls from Poland to the rest of the world over VOIP

Tags: cellphones, poland

(I guess this classifies as a travel question)

I'm in Poland now.
I'm looking for the best (cheap and good voice quality) VOIP provider for making phone calls to the rest of Europe and rest of the world.
Currently I am using Skype which looks OK for me.

I was wondering whether there is anything better.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on where exactly you want to call really; **Each VoIP company offers different prices for different countries**! You should specify the list of countries that you wanna call and check the cheapest options! For example I use [dialnow](http://dialnow.com/) for calling Iran from Italy (which actually doesn't matter generally for a VoIP call from where you are calling since it is using IP protocol). And I should add that I am really satisfied with that because it costs me less than 2 cents/min for landline and less than 3 cents/min for mobile numbers (for Iran). For rates for other countries check [here](https://www.dialnow.com/en/rates).

I also checked the Viber VoIP call prices (Viber Out) couple of days ago which seemed pretty good (specially to the landlines). You can check its prices [here](https://account.viber.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Use the Betamax [price comparison table](http://backsla.sh/betamax) to find the VoIP provider with the cheapest rates for a given destination. [Dialnow](http://www.dialnow.com/) recommended above is part of the Betamax network as well.